# Ubuntu 18.04- Wifi No networks found

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 18.04, iwlwifi

It was working fine yesterday night, but when I booted this morning firstly it took an awfully long time to boot like 5 minutes and then it wasn't connecting to any WiFi networks and also it isn't able to find any network.I've tried restarting network-manager and stuff but to no avail.Also it takes 5 minutes + to boot each time now.However, my wired connection works fine.

Output of `lshw -C network`

```
root@Hazard:~# lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:e1:ad:53:1d:20
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:128 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94104000-94104fff memory:94100000-94103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 78
       serial: cc:2f:71:03:9e:cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=34.0.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:132 memory:94000000-94001fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:36:6c:ef
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:36:6c:ef
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

Any kind of advice is appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: Something must have changed, was  there an update installed? What kernel version are you on?

Comment: Fixed it! Just removed the interface from /etc/network/interfaces file. Thanks,for your time though.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem: what in particular have you removed?

Comment: In the /etc/network/interfaces file you'll have something like `auto wlp3s0`and lines below it . Delete those.